# Microsoft Azure configure Block Blob limit

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there a way to configure the max Block Blob limit in Azure?

MSFT documentation says that max blocks in a blob is 50k: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs

I want to provision my container bucket with a lower value (less than 50k).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change that limit, you can obviously create blobs with lower amounts of blocks, but you can't change the limit.